# Using helper in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, helper

What helper can I use in **model** to populate **html code** as **string** in **view**?

*This is the method I currently use in my model:*

```
 def state_country_name
    "#{self.name}  (#{self.country.name})"
 end
```

I want to wrapp `{self.country.name}` inside a **span**, with `class: pull-right`.

*I have already tried:*

```
  def state_country_name
    "#{self.name} #{helpers.content_tag(:span, self.country.name, class: "pull-right")}"
  end

  def helpers
    ActionController::Base.helpers
  end
```

**Result**:

```
London <span>England</span>
```

I use the **autocomplete-rails4-gem** and this is my form input:

```
= f.input :city_name, :url => autocomplete_city_name_companies_path, :as => :autocomplete, :id_element => "#company_city_id", input_html: {:value => @company.city.name, class: 'form-control'}
```

Code for my `autocomplete_city_name_companies` action:

```
autocomplete :city, :name, :full => false, :display_value => :state_country_name, :extra_data => [:state_id]
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the model?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, in the view the <span> is in html code instead of string in view.

Comment: Reason I have to do it in model is because I use autocomplete gem.

Comment: Then you should do it in the frontend as well. Never generate HTML in the model

Comment: @MichalSzyndel where in my input I can add it?

Comment: Presentation concerns don't belong in the model. You should either use a decorator/presentor, do this in the JS itself, or use CSS. Personally I'd go the CSS route.

Comment: Gem: rails4-autocomplete [link] (https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete),  by: peterwillcn

Comment: @DaveNewton In my form I have only one method, :city_name and it populates city name and country name. How can I find the country_name

Comment: Can you please include code for that action? `autocomplete_city_name_companies_path`

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I included it. Please see the brief

Comment: Ok, I see that the gem you're using is VERY dumb and promotes stupid programming practices. I don't really know how to do it properly without rewriting half of the gem.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel any other gem you suggest?

Comment: @Rubioli this is a good use case for a presenter - draper is fairly popular.  This will allow you to use the autocomplete gem, and add that method in a clean way.

Comment: I'm not sure if adding another gem is a good idea but presenter is definitely a nice and clean solution!

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I am agree with you. Its going to be much more codes for such a small thing. But thanks PinnyM

Comment: @Rubioli, presenters don't have to be big and bloated, this is not a big thing to write and the benefits of introducing the pattern are long-lived.  I've written some sample code below to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend taking the Presenter approach here, as it'll give you a place to put presentation logic that can work with the ruby models but whose logic does not belong in the model itself.  You can use Draper or one of several other gems that do this, but here is some code to demonstrate how simple this concept really is:

A sample presenter:

```
class CompanyPresenter < Struct.new(:company)
  def state_country_name
    company.country.name
  end

  # act as proxy for unknown methods
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    company.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  end
end

@presentable_company = CompanyPresenter.new(@company)
```

Or if you want to take the decorator approach:

```
module CompanyPresenter
  def state_country_name
    country.name
  end
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  def decorate!
    self.extend CompanyPresenter
  end
end

@company.decorate!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't do it in your models. Instead put your helpers methods in your helpers file.
In your model_helper.rb:

```
def my_helper(model)
html = <<-EOT
<span class="pull-right">{model.country.name}</span>
EOT
html.html_safe
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= my_helper(@model_object) %>
```

Comment: Just beware of using `html_safe` for anything that may not actually be 'safe' (primarily data from an unknown source).